# If I cartwheel, does it count as walking?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

I just got the [EXP Walker](http://www.khwiki.com/EXP_Walker) ability that let's me gain 1 exp for each step I take. Normally, however, I cartwheel everywhere because it is faster than just walking. Does cartwheeling count as walking, and if so, is it the same number of steps for the distance traveled?

Comment: If the game represents the exp with a number somewhere in some menu, it should be pretty simple to test this. If there's no such numerical representation of exp then it might not be that simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, cartwheel counts as steps. And it counts for the same amount for the same distance, so spam cartwheel all you want, it will still be the same amount of EXP gain from running which is slower.

Technically, if you wanted to grind solely on this, it looks like going in small circles is the quickest EXP gain, but it is not a lot, and is much quicker to combine this with a loop of kills. In circles, you can gain about 4 EXP/sec